# smooth data by weekly mean in Rstudio

Tags: r, dplyr, smoothing

How can I create a new column, for example "mean7_num_cases", that its the mean of the last 7 observation of num_Cases for each date. My data :

```
 fecha      num_casos
   <date>         <int>
 1 2020-03-02        72
 2 2020-03-03        84
 3 2020-03-04       100
 4 2020-03-05       188
 5 2020-03-06       273
 6 2020-03-07       289
 7 2020-03-08       369
 8 2020-03-09       648
 9 2020-03-10      1018
10 2020-03-11      1332
```

Answer (score 0):

Zoo's rollmean() is the answer

```
require(zoo)
myData %>%
mutate(
 mean7_num_cases = rollmean( num_casos, align="left")
)
```

Is likely to be what you want (average of previous 7 days)

**EDIT**

```
require(dplyr)
require(zoo)
myData <- tibble("num_casos" = c(1:50))
myData %>%
    mutate( 
            mean7_num_cases = rollmean(num_casos, k=7, fill=NA, align="right")
    )
```

Also you didn't say you needed a tidyverse solution! I just assumed.  But this would work:

```
myData$mean7_num_cases <- rollmean(myData$num_casos, k=7, fill=NA, align="right")
```

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `ean7_num_cases`.
x Input `ean7_num_cases` can't be recycled to size 336.
i Input `ean7_num_cases` is `rollmean(num_casos, align = "left", k = 7)`.
i Input `ean7_num_cases` must be size 336 or 1, not 330.

Comment: Odd error message?  ean7_num_cases - I suggested a variable called mean7_num_cases do you somehow have a space in the name?  But it shouldn't be an input.  Can you post a reproducable example?

Comment: Ah - my bad!  You need to tell it what to do with the bit of data missing the 7 days. fill=NA.  Also I think you want align=right